# zsh git completion reports _git:4113: bad set of key/value pairs for associative array

Tags: git, zsh

I have installed zsh and git on SLES 11 SP2. When I try to trigger an auto complete for a git command I get the following error message:

zsh git completion reports _git:4113:

This is my .zshrc

```
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt appendhistory autocd extendedglob nomatch notify
unsetopt beep
bindkey -v
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/d045803/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

autoload -U colors && colors
PROMPT="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m %{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}%1~ %{$reset_color%}%# "
RPROMPT="[%{$fg_no_bold[yellow]%}%?%{$reset_color%}]"
source ~/.zshgitstatus

source ~/.aliases
source ~/.environment
source /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
```

I have nearly the same setup on my Archlinux box. The git completion works fine there. Do you have any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Robin

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this one on my own. ;-) It seems that the zsh version from the SLES repositories was too old to be used in conjunction with a rather fresh git (which we get from an additional repository). I built zsh from source and tried git completion. Now it works without any issues.